# The classification of local homeomorphisms from a closed line segment into $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Does anyone know a reference to the classifications of local homeomorphisms from a closed line segment into $\mathbb{R^2}$ ? I suspect it is given by the minimal number of self intersections
of the image curve.

Comment: Classification up to a global homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: If the map is given by f:[a,b]\to R^2, I am interested in a classification up to homotopy (in R^2) with endpoints f(a) and f(b) fixed.

Comment: Then my guess is that you can homotope anything into the straight line segment, though preserving the local homeomorphism property along the way will give a bit of headache.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I've got to rethink my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Fact**. Every local homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R^2$ is homotopic (through local homeomorphisms, without moving the endpoints) to a polygonal path.

Once the fact is proved, one can reduce the number of intermediate vertices by homotoping the broken line $a_{i-1}a_ia_{i+1}$  to $a_{i-1}a_{i+1}$. When the intermediate vertices are gone, we have a line segment. Hence, the proposed classification has only one class.

*Proof of the fact*: By partitioning $[0,1]$, the problem reduces to the case of a homeomorphism  $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$. Let $\Phi$ be a conformal map of $\mathbb C\setminus [0,1]$ onto $\mathbb C\setminus f([0,1])$ with boundary values $\Phi(0)=f(0)$ and $\Phi(1)=f(1)$. Let $\gamma_\kappa$, $0<\kappa<1$, be the circular arc with endpoints $0$ and $1$ and center $1/2-i/\kappa$. The curves $\Phi\circ \gamma_\kappa$, after suitable reparametrization, form a homotopy between $f$ and a smooth  embedding of $ [0,1]$ into the plane. A smooth embedding can be approximated by a polygonal curve, to which it is related by a straight-line homotopy. $\Box$

(There may be an easier proof of the fact, but it escapes me now.)

Comment: I don't follow. Why does it suffice to work with a homeomorphism?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Because when $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ is a  local homeomorphism, one can partition   $[0,1]$ into subintervals on each of which $f$ is a homeomorphism. The homotopy to polygonal path fixes the endpoints. The concatenation of polygonal paths is also a polygonal path. (OK, one has to make sure that after concatenation we don't get overlap of successive segments, but this holds generically, e.g., if all of them have different slopes).

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Nice argument!